# JOLT json array on a match apply String default

Tags: java, json, jolt

Having the following **input** json:

```json
{
  "familyMembers": [
    {
      "name": "Richard",
      "living": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "name": "Napoleon",
      "living": "No"
    }
  ]
}
```

the goal is to change `"living": "Yes"` to `"living": "true"`, so that desired **output** would be like this:

```json
{
  "familyMembers" : [
    {
      "firstName" : "Richard",
      "living": "true"
    },
    {
      "firstName" : "Napoleon",
      "living": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following **spec** does not produce a desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "familyMembers": {
        "*": {
          "name": "familyMembers[&1].firstName",
          "living": {
            "Yes": {
              "#true": "familyMembers[&1].living"
            },
            "*": {
              "#false": "familyMembers[&1].living"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The `living` field is not included.
If the `familyMember` is changed from an array to a map, then the `living` field is included in the output with the expected value like in this example: http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#hashDefault

I've been struggling with this case for couple of days now with various combinations of `&, [], #` and digits. No luck so far.

A spec like this

```json
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "familyMembers": {
      "*": {
        "name": "familyMembers[&1].firstName",
        "living": {
          "Yes": {
            "#true": "familyMembers[#].living"
          },
          "*": {
            "#false": "familyMembers[#].living"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

produces

```json
{
  "familyMembers" : [
    {
      "firstName" : "Richard",
      "living" : [
        "true",
        "false"
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName" : "Napoleon"
    }
  ]
}
```

which is **not** what is required.

Any hints or help are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by symbolizing the other case by `*` than `living` as in your conditional logic nested within the object with key name `living` as `Yes` vs. `*`. Then, convert the key names `familyMembers` and `living` by appropriate `&` substitution as counting the `{` signs upto the level to reach their conforming names along with bracketed substitutions(`[&1]`and`[&3]`) which should reach the conforming index symbol under `familyMembers` array.

For example you'll count twice `{` in order to reach `living` key from its counterpart, and replace the leaf `living`s with `&2` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "familyMembers": {
        "*": {
          "living": {
            "Yes": {
              "#true": "&4[&3].&2"
            },
            "*": {
              "#false": "&4[&3].&2"
            }
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my, you're amazing. Never in the world would I have figured out this combination of ampersands by myself. Thank you very much!